# angular - Como substituir setInterval?

Tags: angular, setinterval

Atualmente estou fazendo um projeto e preciso pegar uma informação do banco que seja atualizada e para isso estou dando um get a cada 5 segundos utilizando o setInterval. Mas eu sei que esse não é o melhor dos mundos, então gostaria de saber o que fazer.

Já ouvi falarem sobre subscription ou algo do tipo, mas não faço a menor ideia de como implementar.

```js
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/core/services/api.service';

 ngOnInit() {
    this.getFiles();
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.getFiles();
    }, 5000);
  }
  
  
  getFiles() {
    const files = this.apiService.getFiles().subscribe(data => {
        return data['response'];
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dá para trocar o **setInterval()** do Vanilla pelo **[Observable.timer](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-timer)** com Angular, basta importar as **libs** necessárias e utilizá-lo, pode ver um exemplo funcionando [aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-observable-interval), no exemplo é utilizado tbm o método **`takeWhile(() => this.alive)`** que executa o `timer` apenas com o componente em questão **ativo**, no caso vc nem precisa de uma função para realizar a requisição Http, vc já pode incluí-la junto dos métodos:

```
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/core/services/api.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeWhile';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer';

ngOnInit() {
  Observable.timer(0,5000)  // Seta o timer para cada 5 segundos
  .takeWhile(() => this.alive) // Apenas com o componente ativo
  .subscribe(() => {
    const files = this.apiService.getFiles().subscribe(data => {
      return data['response'];
    }, error => {
    console.log(error);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Mas não da pra fazer atualização somente se houver mudança? Porque dessa forma ele continuará a fazer requisição a cada 5s neh?

Comment: Mas atualização de que, não deixou claro na pergunta??

Comment: Você tem razão. Mas a atualização está relacionada com o valor da variável files.